# array value to be the key in the zend form select element

Tags: arrays, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a zend form and in that form I have a select box which I create like this:

```
$e = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('user_status');
$e->setLabel('Status');
$e->addMultiOptions(Model_User::$STATUS);
$e->setRequired(false);
$this->addElement($e);
```

The Model_User::$STATUS array looks like this:

```
public static $STATUS = array(
    1   =>  'creating user',
    2   =>  'creating book',
    3   =>  'book created',
    4   =>  'book send'
);
```

The output is as following:

```
<select name="user_status" id="user_status">
   <option value="0" label="creating user">creating user</option>
   <option value="1" label="creating book" selected="selected">creating book</option>
   <option value="2" label="book created">book created</option>
   <option value="3" label="book send">book send</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want the output to be like is like this:

```
<select name="user_status" id="user_status">
   <option value="creating user" label="creating user">creating user</option>
   <option value="creating book" label="creating book" selected="selected">creating book</option>
   <option value="book created" label="book created">book created</option>
   <option value="book send" label="book send">book send</option>
</select>
```

To make a long story short:
I want the array value to be the key in the zend form. How do I achieve this without changen the status array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just pre-process Model_User::$STATUS var.

```
$statuses = array();
foreach (Model_User::$STATUS as $status) {
    $statuses[$status] = $status;
}
```

And then set multioptions

```
$e->addMultiOptions($statuses);
```